# why google Admob ads not showing up

Tags: android, admob, ads

I just create an android app and wants to integrate ads from my google AdMob account. but Ads do not show up.
But when I test my app from the developer's guidance as they provide sample id's for banner and interstitial ads and also for app id the app work fine but as soon as I put banner id, interstitial ads id and app id from my Admob account then the problem occurred. I did not publish my app till now to play store and I just created my AdMob account does it take time to verify or any suggestion why ads not showing up.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "Problem occurs"?

Answer (score 0):

some common issues are :

- Make sure you have updated AdMob with your payment details.
- Make sure that the ads you created in AdMob are banner ads.
- Check your AdMob dashboard to see the status of your ads, are they active?
- Verify you used the correct Ad Unit Id.
- Give it 24 hours, it can take time for an ad to become active in your
  region

if you do not have traffic on your app Admob will not show ads on your app and if you Will publish your app on play store then AdMob will show ads on your app without traffic read New (privacy policy) if you link your app (published on play store) with Admob then your account will not be suspended directly AdMob will always give you a warning

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if your ad unit id is incorrect, UI will show nothing although the design view will show the AdView.

Make sure you have a valid ad unit id, I used this test ad for a banner: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111.

It's not the app id, it's a different id.